# How to cleanup temp files using multer

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, multer

My nodejs app accepts file uploads from users with permission that's enforced by express middleware, and it uses [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer).

A typical route authenticates, checks if the user is permitted, then does the import, e.g.:

```
router.post('/:id/import', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), permit('admin'), function(req, res, next) {
    MyClass.doImport(req.file.path).then(function(result) {
        res.json(result);
    }).catch(function(error) {
        res.status(500).json(error);
    });
});
```

When there's no error, this works great, and the import function deletes the file.  But in the case of an error (like an invalid or non-permitted user), the uploaded file is created and remains on disk.

I'd like to not create any files on disk until all of the the permission middleware has run successfully.  I've tried using multer as very end of the chain, i.e.:

```
var app = express();

app.use( // ...

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(multer({dest:'./tmp/'}).single('file'));
```

but on an auth error, I still end up with a file in tmp.

How can I avoid creating a file on disk until all other middleware passes?

If that's not possible, can I add a middleware function that runs only if there's a file attachment and there's an error upstream?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move your `multer` middleware so that it gets executed only right before the relevant route handler(s). That way if any other middleware "rejects" the request, you do not have temporary files left over. For example:

```
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated())
    return next();
  res.redirect('/');
}
var fileUpload = multer({dest:'./tmp/'}).single('file');

var app = express();
// ...
app.use(passport.initialize());
// ...
app.put('/upload', isLoggedIn, fileUpload, function(req, res) {
  // use `req.file`
});
```

Comment: That did it.  Thanks!  I forgot that those router methods are really just the ends of the middleware chain.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the combination of [cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron) and 'fs' modules to do this task on a regular basis. you just need to put this code in app.js .
I had to delete all temp files and folder on a regular basis.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
var temp_folder_path = path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'uploads');

     /*
        Seconds: 0-59
        Minutes: 0-59
        Hours: 0-23
        Day of Month: 1-31
        Months: 0-11
        Day of Week: 0-6 // 0 = Sunday
       * cronjob for deleting temp files from public/upload folders
       * this cronjob runs from Monday through Friday at midnight 12:00 
    */
    new CronJob('00 00 00 * * 1-5', function () {
    console.log('deleting all temporary file from public/uploads/*');
    deleteFolderRecursive(temp_folder_path)
}, null, true, 'America/Los_Angeles');


// Used for deleting all files and sub-folders from 'public/upload/*'
// Multer : stores temporary files in this folder
var deleteFolderRecursive = function (path) {
    if (fs.existsSync(path)) {
        fs.readdirSync(path).forEach(function (file, index) {
            var curPath = path + "/" + file;
             if (fs.lstatSync(curPath).isDirectory()) { // recurse
                deleteFolderRecursive(curPath);
                fs.rmdirSync(curPath);
            } else { // delete file
                fs.unlinkSync(curPath);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: 5 years later but I had to comment that this is not a very good solution as it's concurrency sensitive. The cron job might run in the middle of an upload and delete the file currently being imported.